# How to classify string into a person's name or company's name or none of these?

Tags: algorithm, classification

Let's say, I have string say 'John Doe' and I want to determine whether this string is a name of a person, name of a company or none of these.
Every minute more and more strings are coming into my system and the system needs to classify into one of these 3 categories.

Comment: I don't understand the question you're asking.

Comment: can you please collaborate bit.??

Comment: @RitulLakhtariya The word you're looking for is "elaborate". Cheers!

Comment: hahah right typo .. its morning here so hands didnt much support us @Our_Benefactors

Comment: @Our_Benefactors Sorry, I hope the current question is more understandable.

Comment: @RitulLakhtariya Sorry, I hope the current question is more understandable.

Comment: Do you have any lookup table to search with?

Comment: The scope of that question is a little too large for SO, I think.  Generally you'd need to make a statistical model based on a large training set.  No matter what it will be fuzzy -- There are plenty of people John Deere, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a dictionary of strings in different categories to compare them against.

Without a dictionary you would need some kind of AI/machine learning that could do this automatically, but that is far beyond the scope of the kind of answer you'll get here.

Answer (score 1):

NLTK provides the corpora of the most common English words `(nltk.corpus.words.words('en'))` and most common English names `nltk.corpus.names.words())`

Answer (score 1):

Use gensim word2vec, it's a library provided by google where it have vectors and relationship for all the words.

Now when you enter the text to the system, first you'll get vector for your word.
On the top of this you can apply any classification algo to categorize your task.

Hope this help!